# ¿Javascript sin extension .js?

Tags: javascript, html

Si tengo un javascript externo y lo declaro en html, pero este archivo no tiene extensión .js a sabiendas que tiene scripts dentro, ¿Sería lo mismo que el archivo contenga extension .js, en relación al rendimiento?

Comment: Hola Pachi, estás realizando muchas preguntas que han sido marcadas como de baja calidad o demasiado amplias por la comunidad. Por favor, lee [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve] y edita tus publicaciones para añadir más detalles que ayuden concretar el problema y a aclarar qué es lo que quieres.

Comment: ¿Por qué se vería afectado *el rendimiento*? ¿Qué te hace pensar que iría más lento o más rápido? ... Y por favor, presta atención a los errores de ortografía al publicar

Comment: Buenas bienvenido a **StackOverflow** en español por favor antes de preguntar primero ve [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y revisa también [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) edita tu pregunta y mejorarla para tener una respuesta que realmente te ayude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No afecta, el rendimiento se basa en la cantidad de código que cargue el sitio para procesar, si deseas aumentar el rendimiento minificas el archivo, llevándolo a pocas lineas de código(ideal en una sola), eliminando espacios y comentarios, definir o no una extencion, no traería consigo aumento de rendimiento, lo que podría ocasionarte es problema, por ejemplo en el momento de editarlo el IDE no reconoce el tipo de archivo y no te ayudaría por ejemplo con el auto completado de código.

Comment: okey entocnes la unica diferencia seria el reconocimiento dentro d eun editor si no posee .js, gracias ;)

Comment: exacto, también puede influir de otras maneras, pero en principio si, solo en eso

Comment: Revisar [answer]. **Tienes reputación para realizar comentarios**, ayúdanos a conservar la calidad en el sitio comentando preguntas que no cumplen con lo definido en el [help],

Answer (score -1):

Todos los archivos tienen extensión. Quizas no lo veas porque usas windows y windows por defecto te oculta las extensiones pero puedes verlo dandole click derecho al archivo y en propiedades ver la extensión del archivo (js,html,css,etc)

Comment: mi pregunta es en base a js externo, afecta el rendimiento que el script este en un archivo comun o de .js ?

Comment: No afecta en nada.

Comment: Un archivo .js es un archivo común

Comment: Revisar [answer]. Cuando tengas suficiente reputación puedes comentar.